# Why Doesn't Work This Package On Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, url, flutter-dependencies

I want to use the `url_launcher` package. This package clearly runs on Android 11 virtual device but doesn't work on real Android 11 and Android 12 devices.  However, it works on 9 and 7.

Here is my `build.gradle` configs

```
defaultConfig {
  // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
  applicationId "com.example.gelir_mii"
  // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
  // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
  minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
  targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
  versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
  versionName flutterVersionName
}
```

And here is the code block

```
void openWhatsapp() async {
  var whatsapp = '+9033823498234';
  var whatsappURL = Uri.parse(
    'whatsapp://send?phone=$whatsapp&text=Merhaba, danışmanlık hakkında bilgi almak istiyorum.');

  if (await canLaunchUrl(whatsappURL)) {
    await launchUrl(whatsappURL);
  } else {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      const SnackBar(
        content: Text("WhatsApp is not installed on the device"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add any URL schemes passed to canLaunchUrl as  entries in your AndroidManifest.xml, otherwise it will return false in most cases starting on Android 11 (API 30) or higher. A  element must be added to your manifest as a child of the root element.

```
<!-- Provide required visibility configuration for API level 30 and above -->
<queries>
  <!-- If your app checks for SMS support -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="sms" />
  </intent>
  <!-- If your app checks for call support -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="tel" />
  </intent>
</queries>
```

Please look at the pub config:
https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

Comment: Sir I do that but still not work

Answer (score 0):

For sending the whatsapp message using your code, I hope you might have already read **Readme.md** section for [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) and have already configured the url scheme as described there.

After the readme android & iOS configuration check, if your code is not working then check for,

```
var whatsappURL = Uri.parse(
    'whatsapp://send?phone=$whatsapp&text=Merhaba, danışmanlık hakkında bilgi almak istiyorum.');
```

So, check that your **$whatsapp** number is in format like 911234567890, if your phone number does contain any kind of special characters like, **'+', ' ', '-'** then remove it and format it.